# Google Sheets query: filter columns selecting rows with specific condition: "select * WHERE "row5" = "ColContas" OR "row5" = "ColNum""

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I've used query a lot of times to filter rows, like `select * WHERE R = "ColContas"` in this case filtering rows and selecting only the ones where R has the "ColContas" tag.

This time I need to filter columns, I just want to select the columns where in line 5 there is "ColContas" or "ColNum". That is to say, this:

[image]

Should turn into this:

[image]

Should be something like `select * WHERE “row5” = “ColContas” OR “row5” = “ColNum”`

How could I do that?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NZm96pF1ML6osI5faTqaTCWbMoXJxrJNYThg6vzenaA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A5:G); "where Col1 matches 'ColContas|ColNum'"; 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there. ColContas had only the first row fulfilled. I will edit the post to be able to paste the print. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I've made a copy here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NZm96pF1ML6osI5faTqaTCWbMoXJxrJNYThg6vzenaA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Nevermind. It is apparently a google sheets bug in my sheet, when I copied in a new sheet it worked.